# Selenium Webdriver Expected Conditions is not working

Tags: selenium

I'm new to selenium Webdriver, and I'm trying to get some stuff done with click and waits like I used to in Selenium IDE. There is a form that the user has to answer several interview questions, The page reloads after the user clicks save and continue and they are taken to the next question. This element that I'm getting is the div where the text for that question is held, for some reason, it keeps checking the text immediately instead of waiting, or the continue button isn't being properly clicked. Anyone know what is going on here?

```
browser.findElement(By.linkText("Save and Continue")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, 3);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(browser.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='inquiryForm']/div/div/div[3]/div/div")), "Question 2 of 8"));
System.out.println(browser.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='inquiryForm']/div/div/div[3]/div/div")).getText());
```

Comment: Not an answer for your posted question but I highly recommend to clean up your XPath calls - if you have any change in your inquiryForm EVER you'll have to change up that xpath value.

Comment: @Dean Can you post the html?

Comment: I guess the page is not move fast enough so the wait still pass with the old check. Could check if the new page is loaded before verifying the text?

Comment: @Dean, try to increase wait time from 3 seconds to 30 seconds. It might help.

Comment: I don't think I can post the HTML, but I can tell you from the println that I'm looking at the right element. @JonahOberloh, how else could I get this element, it doesn't have an id, and the classname is shared among other elements. I do not develop this website, I'm just a QA

Comment: Just share with me the singular HTML element through the dev tools. There has to be some sort of unique HTML that you can create a path off of. I understand that you're QA, but just right click>inspect element and you should be good to go from there.

Comment: <div class= "pull-left editReferenceLeft">
    Question 1 of 8
    </div>

Comment: @TonyBui I don't know how to check if the new page is loaded?